# How to choose between two items based on a percentage in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to choose between two things based on a percentage, but I don't know how to code it correctly. I am trying to choose between item *a* and item *b* when the chance of item *a* being chosen is 33.33% and item *b* is 66.67%. I'm not sure if I should use if else statements or something else. I would like to know how to code it in objective c, but any advice would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the percentages are fixed, it's quite easy:

```
int result = (arc4random_uniform(3) == 0) ? a : b;
```

Essentially, this says "if a uniformly distributed non-negative integer strictly less than 3 is exactly equal to 0 (which happens 1/3 of the time), then the value of this expression is a, else it is b".

Comment: Oh ok I see so how would I make it to where when it chose a the message would say "hi" and when it chose b the message would say "bye"?

Comment: Would I do it like this `if (int result = arc4random_uniform(3) == 0) ? a : b) { Label.text [NSString StringWithFormat:@"Hi"]; } else { Label.text [NSString StringWithFormat:@"Bye"];`

Comment: You seem to be unfamiliar with basic features of the C and Objective-C languages. You should probably learn them first.

Comment: For completeness, though: `NSString *message = (arc4random_uniform(3) == 0) ? @"Hi" : @"Bye"; label.text = message;`

Comment: Yeah I'm new at this that's why I'm asking these questions, I'm just trying to learn how to do it, but I get confused at times. Thanks for the help though.